# How can I search for multiple tags in Google Bookmarks?

Tags: search, google-bookmarks

Google Bookmarks is a good tools for me，but sometimes i need search tags , the query words should be like this:

```
label:php
```

if I need to search for more tag，how to input the query words ?

```
label:php and javascript??
```

Answer (score 4):

As with most of Google's products, you simply add the same operator again.

In your example, you would use:

```
label:php label:javascript
```

If you have a label that is more than one word, use quotes:

```
label:"label 1" label:"label 2"
```